# Wpdb prepare was called incorrectly

Tags: php, jquery, sql, wordpress

I want to prepare my data to avoid SQL Injections. So my current working code to show a list of data from a table's column:

```
global $wpdb;
$sliders = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT alias, title FROM wp_revslider_sliders', ARRAY_A);

echo '<select name="revslider">';
if ($sliders) {
    foreach($sliders as $slide){
        echo '<option value="'.$slide['alias'].'" '.($select_revslider_shortcode == $slide['alias'] ? 'selected=""' : '').'>'.$slide['title'].'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

I need to use `$wpdb->prepare` to be sure that my datas are correctly brought from the db. My current progress:

```
$sliders = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id, alias, title FROM wp_revslider_sliders", ARRAY_A));
```

This isn't working. I get a notice:

> Notice: wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query argument of
>   wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder.

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong with my code?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prepare method is used to protect against SQL injection. You'd use it when you want to insert variables into your query. It accepts placeholders such as %s for string, %d for integers and %f for floats.

Your query doesn't have any variables so you don't need the prepare method. You're seeing an error because you aren't using any placeholders.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#protect-queries-against-sql-injection-attacks

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I will go and check your reference.

Comment: That isn't the only benefit of a prepared statement - you can execute one query multiple times when prepared. It's just the main usage is for query protection. It's weird that WordPress doesn't let this happen properly and reports it as a notice :/

Comment: @nathan-dawson hi is it necessary when we are using $wpdb->get_results ?